# C++ How to check std::wstring with forward slash is equal

Tags: c++

I am a C# developer so this one I am having trouble with.

I have a `std::wstring` object which is this: `msgItem.path`.

That has a value in it of `L"/Shared Documents"`, where I am trying to say if `!=` to `_TS("/Shared Documents")`, but that is not working.

Any idea how I can do this correctly? I have been googling, but can't find an example.

Right now, my code is doing this:

`if(msgItem.path != _TS("/Shared Documents"))`

This keeps getting into the `if` statement, which I don't want.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. `std::wstring` would compare `_TS("/Shared Documents")` well. Are you sure `msgItem.path` is `std::wstring` and not `wchar_t*`, and you are coding with C++, not C?

Comment: when I hover over that msgItem.path object the path shows std::wstring...

Comment: What is `_TS()`, what does it map to, and under what conditions? That is not a standard macro.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say `msgItem.path` is a `std::wstring`, which is a container of `wchar_t` characters, you should compare it against a wide string literal that also uses `wchar_t` characters, eg:

```
if (msgItem.path != L"/Shared Documents")
```

It doesn't make sense to compare `path` to whatever `_TS()` maps the string literal to, unless `path` is itself an alias that maps its character type using the same criteria that `_TS()` uses for its mapping.

Comment: I think you may spend a few more words to describe what's the issue. The user (and who will read it in future) would appreciate to know the reason of your correction i guess.